# Next.js multi language app with 2 different UI structures

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a Next.js, Express web application.

I want to make my website with 2 languages, which are English and Arabic.

I read about i18n, but it will not work.

In most languages, like English and Spanish as an example, they are both LTR directed, so translating will work.

But I can't only translate in Arabic, because I also have to make the components RTL, so I have to change some CSS in the Arabic version. (different UI structure)

So the best solution is to make 2 pages for each page, one Arabic and one English.

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
 
function BasePage () { 
    const router = useRouter() 
    return ( 
        router.locale === 'en' ? ( 
            <EnglishPage /> 
        ) : ( 
            <ArabicPage /> 
        ) 
    ) 
}
```

But this method will not work because it will be very bad for SEO, since nothing is going to be SSRd all pages will be components.

So is there anything else I can do to make 2 pages for each? Or should I consider finding a solution in redirecting?

Comment: You may wanna look at using  `dir="rtl"` in `<html>` tag, and handle other things with CSS. Also checkout https://github.com/airbnb/react-with-direction for rendering conditional RTL components

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make two components for each language. You can instead use i18n library e.g. [next-intl](https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app) and utilize CSS logical properties in your CSS with the `dir` attribute in your `<html>` element.

Quoting from my answer to another question:

CSS provides built-in support for [Logical Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_logical_properties_and_values). This feature simplifies styling by allowing you to define properties once, with the browser automatically adjusting them based on the parent's `dir` attribute.

For instance, instead of specifying `padding-left: 1rem`, you should opt for `padding-inline-start: 1rem`.

### Syntax:

```css
[property]-[axis]-[direction]: [value]
```

- The axis can be either `inline` or `block`.
- The direction can be `start` or `end`.
  The supported properties include:
- padding
- margin
- inset (top, left, bottom, right)
- text-align
- border
- border-radius
- scroll-padding
- scroll-margin

To utilize logical properties, set the parent's page direction (or the `html` tag) as follows:

```html
// This is a JSX code
<html dir={lang === "ar" ? "rtl" : "ltr"}>
```

Subsequently, employ logical properties instead of physical ones. For example:

| Don't | Do |
| --- | --- |
| `padding-left` | `padding-inline-start` |
| `padding-right` | `padding-inline-end` |
| `padding-top` | `padding-block-start` |
| `padding-bottom` | `padding-block-end` |
| `margin-left` | `margin-inline-start` |
| `margin-right` | `margin-inline-end` |
| `border-left` | `border-inline-start` |
| `border-right` | `border-inline-end` |
| `border-top-left-radius` | `border-start-start-radius`, `border-start-end-radius`, `border-end-start-radius`, `border-end-end-radius` |
| `text-align: left` | `text-align: start` |
| `scroll-padding-left` | `scroll-padding-inline-start` |
| `scroll-padding-right` | `scroll-padding-inline-end` |
| `scroll-margin-left` | `scroll-margin-inline-start` |
| `scroll-margin-right` | `scroll-margin-inline-end` |

By doing this, `padding-inline-start` functions as `padding-left` in LTR languages and as `padding-right` in RTL languages. For top-to-down languages like Japanese, use `padding-block-start` instead of `padding-top`.